# Is a multiline #warning directive possible?

Tags: c#, warnings

I read [here](http://codeidol.com/csharp/essential-csharp/Operators-and-Control-Flow/Csharp-Preprocessor-Directives/) that "Each preprocessor directive begins with a hash symbol (#), and all preprocessor directives must appear on one line. A newline rather than a semicolon indicates the end of the directive."

But I was wondering if maybe there is a trick to create a multiline #warning because, in an early stage of some code, I'm writing a warning that spans more than the width of the screen.

Comment: why write a warning that takes that long?

Comment: What @DanielA.White said. Warnings should be pretty concise. Perhaps a shortened URL to a long message would be useful to consider, if it really has to be really long?

Comment: You could always make the warning say "#warning effected lines:(44-71)" or something like that.

Comment: if this were C, you could use a backslash for line continuation, but this doesn't seem to be allowed in C#. Maybe you could use multiple `#define`s that hold parts of your message?

Comment: I guess this time I started something more like a story than a warning (it begins with "here we may have a situation where... " and it goes on and on), but still I think it should be a valid thing to write 2-3 lines for a warning.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle That's a good idea, I wrote a short one line excerpt of the #warning that also says that the next comment lines are holding the details.

Comment: @l4mpi from MSDN, the C# reference: "The #define directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is typically done in C and C++."

Comment: @victorvartan, thanks for the info... seems like the C# preprocessor is even more useless than I thought. Another reason for me to never use C# ^^

Comment: @victorvartan Would you like me to post this as the answer?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Although it is an alternative solution, I'm not seeing it as a straight answer to the question. I will wait a couple of days to see if someone comes up with a definitive answer to wether a true multiline warning can be inserted, and if no accurate answer is received I will close the question.

Comment: @victorvartan That's probably the correct thing to do.

Comment: It's nice to have a special macro that can be set before a header is included, and unset after it is included, like __myinterface_warnings, so that if the header is forced into situations where it has to do something clever, like use a custom implementation because some dependency is missing, it would tell you a nice well formatted story saying what it had to do. It doesn't take much preprocessor power to skip over it, and it saves so much time, and allows you to try help the header work optimally by satisfying things that bother it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx:

```
A preprocessor directive must be the only instruction on a line.
```

So, It's not possible.

Comment: Ok, it seems pretty clear that the preprocessor directives are one line only, so I'll accept the answer. For a workaround to this restriction see @0x7fffffff 's comments.